# How to round up to only 2 decimals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rounding

How do I round my `procent for 10 Tommer` and `procent for 11 Tommer` up to the closest 2 decimals whole number so it will be like `0.00` instead of alot of 0's?

```
Declare @omkreds numeric(36,8), @diameternu numeric(5,2),
@profilhøjdenu numeric(5,2), @omkredsnu numeric(36,8)

SELECT @profilhøjdenu = (@bredenu*@profilnu)/100
SELECT @diameternu = @tommernu * 25.4
SELECT @omkredsnu=(@profilhøjdenu *2 + @diameternu)*PI()

select [Daekstørelsen CEILING((@omkredsnu-[Omkreds for 10 Tommer])/@omkredsnu*100*100)/100 as "procent for 10 Tommer",
(select CEILING((@omkredsnu-[Omkreds for 11 Tommer])/@omkredsnu*100*100)/100) as "procent for 11 Tommer",
    from [dbo].[daek];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Round function is SQL Server.  You can pass it the precision to round by.  For example ROUND(748.58, -1) will round to 750.

Comment: i had been trying around with ceiling and round but could only get it to give me a whole number with alot of decimals but what about the filtering between so it will only show the result that are between 5 and -5